# Netlogo About this judgment " 0 < A < 1 ", how can we program with Netlogo?

Tags: if-statement, precision, netlogo

For the following judgment, " 0 < A < 1 ", how can I program this? I already checked the Netlogo dictionary and programming guide, however there were no information especially for the judgment " 0 < A < 1 ". " A " is a probability distribution, but I puts " precision () 0 " for not to use to add any decimal point.

```
set gamma-A precision (random-gamma (α) (β))0
if 0 < gamma-A < 1 ;;This does not work,,
```

Thank you.

Comment: How about `if 0 < gamma-A and gamma-A < 1 [ ...`?

Comment: As I understand it though, your condition will never be satisfied, as with precision 0 you will never have anything but an integer.

Comment: The model ran without problems with the advised code. Thank you!

Comment: Right on, glad it worked for you!

Comment: Luke C, would you submit your solution as an answer so this question can be marked as answered?